# remote ssh command not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

The following local command on host xyz provides the following correct output

```
taskset -p `ps -ef | grep ripit | grep -v grep| awk '{print \$2}'`
pid 21352's current affinity mask: 1
```

When I run the following command and ssh to xyz host I also get correct output

```
ssh xyz "ps -ef | grep ripit | grep -v grep |awk '{print \$2}'"
21352
```

However When I add the taskset command and run remotely on host xyz host  i get this incorrect output.

```
ssh xyz "taskset -p `ps -ef | grep ripit | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'`"
sched_getaffinity: No such process
failed to get pid 27599's affinity
bash: line 1: 32127: command not found
```

I tried many different single and double quote combination and I used escape character all over the place to no avail. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with another subshell? maybe with `$(ps -ef| grep ripit | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: I did try> I had to add () and then I had to use escape character for the  ssh xyz "taskset -p \`ps -ef | grep ripit | grep -v grep |awk '{print \$2}'\` .. It does provide the answer but it also produces garbage. The output starts up saying that taskset command is incorrect and gives all the options, and then it actually executes the command on the PID. So at least I have gotten further

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested with your exact commands, but

```
ssh host 'lsof -p $(pgrep program)'
```

worked for me

Comment: great but this is not what I'm trying to do .. is it now!

Answer (score 0):

For running commands remotely:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT='
#Your commands
'
sshpass -p<pass> ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p <port> user@host "$SCRIPT"
```

Comment: we do not have sshpass

Comment: You can install sshpass...you can also use this structure with out sshpass and you can do: `ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p <port> user@host "$SCRIPT"` ... No `ssh -o` is correct...you can also do: `ssh -p <port> user@host "$SCRIPT"`

Answer (score 0):

> When I add the taskset command and run remotely on host xyz host
>
> ```
> ssh xyz "taskset -p `ps -ef | grep ripit | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'`"
> ```

Here, the command substitution between `` is executed on the local host and yields a local process ID - no wonder that there is `No such process` on the remote host. If you escape the backquotes like

```
ssh xyz "taskset -p \`ps -ef | grep ripit | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'\`"
```

the command substitution is executed on the remote host and yields the correct process ID.